# const auto& for storing functions results, is it worthwhile?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, const-reference

Let assume that we have a function that returns a complex object like `std::string`:

```
std::string find_path(const std::string& filename);
```

Is it worthwhile to store the result of calling that method in the `const auto&`?

```
void do_sth() {
   //...
   const auto& path = find_path(filename);
   //...
}
```

That kind of approach prevents copying/moving the object. So it is good. But on the other hand, `auto` has been introduced to unify the left side of assignation. Herb Sutter in his presentation from CppCon2014 mentions about C++ left-to-right modern style https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64 (39:00-45:00).

In C++98 storing the `std::string` at const ref was fine. How is it in C++11?

***Update (2016-07-27 2:10 GMT+0):***

Sorry, my question was not precise. I meant the coding style - is it better to add `const &` or just stay with `auto` only and let the compiler do whatever it want.

Updated example:

```
unsigned int getTimout() { /* ... */ }

int getDepth() { /* ... */ }

std::string find_path(const std::string& filename,
                      unsigned int timeout,
                      int depth) { /* ... */ } 

void open(const std::string& path) { /* ... */ }
```

Two approaches:

```
void do_sth() {
   //...
   auto timeout = getTimeout();
   auto depth = getDepth();
   const auto& path = find_path(filename, timeout, depth);
   open(path)
   //...
}
```

vs

```
void do_sth() {
   //...
   auto timeout = getTimeout();
   auto depth = getDepth();
   auto path = find_path(filename, timeout, depth);
   open(path);
   //...
}
```

The question: should we

- use `const auto&` to store complex return objects and `auto` for primitives, or
- use `auto` for everything to keep the left-to-right modern C++ style that Herb mentioned in his presentation (link above).

Comment: Never return (take a function return value)  to temporaries as reference.

Comment: Have a read about NVRO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233879/move-or-named-return-value-optimization-nrvo

Comment: @DieterLücking "C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself"
https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: related/not quite a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement

Comment: I am uncertain what your question parameters are.  How is it ... with respect to what considerations?  Alternatives?  In comparison to C++98?  "Tell me everything" is asking for a chapter in a book...

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318257/const-reference-to-temporary-vs-return-value-optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++98 storing the std::string at const ref was fine. How is it in C++11?

Binding a const reference to a temporary string object is fine in C++11. It still has the same behaviour as before.

The theoretical cost of copy-initialization from a temporary (avoiding of which is the advantage of using a const reference) has been greatly reduced in C++11, since moving a string is far cheaper than copying.

The practical cost of copy-initialization has not changed with optimizing compilers, because they may elide the copy/move anyway, so there is no cost - although, whether that is possible, depends on how `find_path` is implemented.

---

If you absolutely want to avoid copying/moving the returned string and cannot assume copy elision, then you must create the object outside the function, and pass it to the function by reference. Binding a reference to the return value is not sufficient.

If you want to avoid copying/moving the returned string and can assume copy elision, then using a regular object is just as good as a const reference.